# convert RAW query to Laravels Query Builder standards

Tags: jquery, laravel-4, build, converters, query-builder

I would like to convert my raw query using laravel Query Builder markup to make it compatible with the [bllim](https://github.com/bllim/laravel4-datatables-package) Datatable package but I have problems

The working RAW query

```
  SELECT 
        publisher_name, 
        SUM(sales) AS sales, 
        SUM(comission) AS comission, 
        SUM(sale_total) AS publisher_total_sale,
        sumOfTotalSales
  FROM reports_summary,
       (SELECT SUM(sale_total) AS sumOfTotalSales FROM reports_summary) AS subTotalSales
 WHERE campaign = ?   
 GROUP BY publisher_name, sumOfTotalSales 
 ORDER BY publisher_total_sale DESC', array($campaign)
```

What I tried but not working

```
DB::table(DB::raw('SELECT SUM(sale_total) AS sumOfTotalSales FROM reports_summary) AS subTotalSales'))
            ->sum('sales')   
            ->sum('comission')           
            ->sum('sale_total AS publisher_total_sale')
            ->select( 'publisher_name', 'sumOfTotalSales')
            ->where('campaign',$campaign)
            ->groupBy('publisher_name', 'sumOfTotalSales')
            ->orderBy('publisher_total_sale','desc')
            ->get();
```

How would I transform in a proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use DB view instead and let laravel work with it just like with any table.

However, this is how to do it with query builder:

```
DB::table(DB::raw('reports_summary, SELECT SUM(sale_total) AS sumOfTotalSales FROM reports_summary) as subTotalSales'))    
 ->selectRaw('publisher_name, sunOfTotalSales, sum(sales) as sales, sum(comission) as comission, sum(sale_total) as publisher_total_sale')
 ->where('campaign',$campaign)
 ->groupBy('publisher_name', 'sumOfTotalSales')
 ->orderBy('publisher_total_sale','desc')
 ->get();
```

Comment: thanks a lot the Query is working. I like the idea with the view I will make it

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use the Bllim laravel package to produce the datatable (which works very well). Your query won't work.

You need to pass the query to the datatables package as outlined in the documentation for the package. Don't pass a collection.

By including get() to the query you are returning a collection - this will fail.

Your approach should be:

```
$data = DB::table(DB::raw('reports_summary, SELECT SUM(sale_total) AS sumOfTotalSales FROM     reports_summary) as subTotalSales'))    
->selectRaw('publisher_name, sunOfTotalSales, sum(sales) as sales, sum(comission) as comission, sum(sale_total) as publisher_total_sale')
->where('campaign',$campaign)
->groupBy('publisher_name', 'sumOfTotalSales')
->orderBy('publisher_total_sale','desc')

return Datatables::of($data)->make();
```

This produces a correcftly formated json to use in the client side datatables. Make sure you have a route pointing to the function that includes this code or use it in a closure, then use that route in your server side script.